# Arrastrar elementos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, html-tabla

Quiero detectar el arrastre de buttons, para que despues, de pendiendo de que buttons se hayan arrastrado, fusionarlos copiando sus textos y metiendolos en un úinco  con rowspan y colspan.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button>1</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>2</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button>3</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>4</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Espero haberme explicado bien, si tenéis preguntas puedo responderlas en los comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien tu problema, lo podrías hacer de la siguiente manera, usando [jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```
<!-- Agregamos Jquery para facilidad en el DOM.- -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- En este script detectamos los clicks en los botones y les colocamos una clase si corresponde, también usamos append para colocar la información de esos botones en un td.- -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('button.apretable').click(function(){

    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }

    $('#resultado').html('');

    $('button.active').each(function(){

        $('#resultado').append($(this).text());

    });

  });

});
</script>

<!-- Le damos un poco de estilo a los botones cuando están seleccionados para poder distinguirlos.- -->
<style>
  .apretable.active{
    background: pink;
  }  
</style>

<!-- El HTML -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="apretable">1</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="apretable">2</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="apretable">3</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="apretable">4</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="resultado" colspan=2>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Dime si tienes alguna duda.

Comment: No quiero que tengas que pulsar, más bien que al arrastrar te detecte... Lo siento por las molestias.

Comment: ¿Quieres poder arrastrar los botones al td#resultado?

Comment: no, quiero arrastrar un button a otro button, y que entonces se junten los button en la misma table con un <td> con los atributos colspan y rowspan

Comment: ¡Entiendo! Considera editar la pregunta y colocar "Arrastrar", hay un mundo de diferencia entre Seleccionar y Arrastrar en Javascript. Te dejo un link que te puede servir: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to, si más tarde sigues con el problema te hago un ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, pero ahora necesito saber cuando hay dos buttons en el mismo sitio para saber cuanto valor ponerle al rowspan